# Touchmove + iOS devices

Tags: jquery, ios

```
$("body").on("touchmove", function(){});
```

This fires every time the user's finger is on the screen, but obviously this only allows the application to fire something only when the user's finger is on the screen (specifically for iOS).

```
$("body").on("touchstart", function(){});
```

From what I found, this is for when the user's finger just touches the screen (fires only once).

```
$("body").on("touchend", function(){});
```

This fires when the scroll event ends (whether user's finger is on the screen or not).

My question is, how can I still calculate movement on an iOS device even if the user's finger isn't on the screen, in which the momentum is still active?

Comment: By the "screen is still moving" do you mean the scroller is still scrolling (due to simulated momentum I'm guessing?)

Comment: Correct. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Check if `$("body").on("scrollstop")` fires instead

Comment: Interesting, ill try that out.

Comment: Wait a second, does that only check if the scroll has stopped. I'm asking if the scroll is still going.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question.